# How would you say "relevant pictures" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

*e.g.* Relevant pictures to Esperanto.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit your question, e.g. add some examples for the uses you intend. This would help a lot especially to non-native speakers of English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[John Well’s dictionary](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/508176) has the following for *relevant*:

> **relevant** (tiu)rilata, koncerna, tiutema, trafa, pria

So I think depending on the context any of these might be suitable. For example:

> Mi kreas afiŝon pri nia loka klubo kaj mi serĉas **bildojn rilatajn al** Esperanto.
>
> Mi volas diskonigi esperanton do mi desegnas **tiutemajn bildojn**.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question lakes context. An other option might be *taŭgaj bildoj*, but it's difficult to give you a relevant answer without more context.

Answer (score 0):

Oni elektus la vortojn "rilataj" aŭ "gravaj", laŭ via devo.